# Why I can not connect to my local server from windows?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, openvpn, centos-7

I have the following setup at home

```
A machine running CentOS7 IP 192.168.15.12
A laptop running Windows10 IP 192.168.15.4
```

I have both computers running also with OpenVPN with a tunnel

```
CentOS7 has the IP 10.8.0.4
and 
Windows10 has IP 10.8.0.3
```

I have had such configuration for a while, all was working fine until today's evening, now I can not connect to my server from Window10 in my local LAN

```
donhk@WINDESKTOP MINGW64 /
$ ssh -v donhk@192.168.15.12
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.15.12 [192.168.15.12] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.15.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.15.12 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I thought it was a problem with ssh on the server side, so I restart it up and I got the same problem, however, **I can ssh to CentOS7 from my cell phone**

then I started the VPN on the Windows10 machine and I tried to contact the server and it worked, so, I can ssh the server through the VPN but not in within the LAN

```
[donhk@i7box ~]$ netstat -plant | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0     28 10.8.0.4:22             10.8.0.1:50001          ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.15.12:22        192.168.15.4:49611      ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

this works

```
 ssh donhk@10.8.0.4
```

this doesn't

```
 ssh donhk@192.168.15.12

$ ping 192.168.15.12
 Pinging 192.168.15.12 with 32 bytes of data:
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.
```

so, the ssh daemon is listening from any IP, now I think is something on the windows side, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well, after struggling with this for 2 days, and after format my windows client it turns out that was a very very odd thing, I just connected the server through a wired network and magically all became to work

[ping working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rADG.png)